# How do I stop vsvarsall.bat (VS2022) from changing my terminal font?

Tags: cmd, visual-studio-2022

I just upgraded (finally) to MSVC 2022. I have a script I wrote (and have been using for *years*) that finds and triggers `vsvarsall.bat` for me at the Console Window / Terminal Window / whatever I’m using. (I spend a lot of time at the Cmd prompt.)

Besides moving everything (finally) into a subdirectory of `C:\Program Files\`, the latest incarnation of Microsoft’s tools *changes my <explicative-deleted> font!*

I like my font (Consolas! lol) with large text (<sub><sup>me ol’ squinty eyes cannae read tiny things any more</sup></sub>). I like my terminal window appearing where I’ve programmed it to go. I don’t need some major application telling me I’m wrong about any of it and changing all my carefully selected presets.

Alas, I haven’t yet been able to figure out ***where*** or ***how*** the font is getting scrubbed.

**Does anyone know where MS’s latest `vcvarsall.bat` changes the font?**
(And preferrably, does anyone know how to stop it?)

Comment: [How to: Change fonts, colors, and themes in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-fonts-and-colors-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)?

Comment: @JosefZ Did you... _read_ my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the telemetry handling code in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\...\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat`. This runs a powershell command which, if run in `cmd.exe`, causes the font to be reset. You can test this by just running `powershell.exe` in the console and seeing if your font changes.

To fix this you can either

1. `set VSCMD_SKIP_SENDTELEMETRY=1` before calling `vcvarsall.bat` to opt out of sending telemetry.
2. Remove the offending powershell line from `VsDevCmd.bat` directly (search for `VSCMD_SKIP_SENDTELEMETRY`).

If you go with option 2 you'll likely need to do this every time you update Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is due to the [synchronization of settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/synchronized-settings-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)?
I would also check the behaviour after using the [ImportandExportSettings tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/import-and-export-settings-command?view=vs-2022) with own setup.